# In a bash script, print command (as a suggestion) on the prompt after the script exit

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, prompt

I'd like to write a shell script that can suggest a command by printing it after the command line prompt.
Then, after the scrip exit, the user would only have to press the [enter] key to run this suggested command.

Given that I'm new to bash, I don't even know if it is  possible to do this. I thought about using a copy-past command, moving the cursor, use the $PS1 variable, without finding a suitable way..

Does anyone have any  clues on how such feature could be implemented  ?

Comment: Just print it to stdout and let them copy and paste it? Ask them if they want to run it before you exit and run it for them if they say yes?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `readline` doesn't provide a way to programmatically add text to the input buffer.

Comment: It may be possible to use something like xte to type into the terminal with a delayed script running in the background but it's not a practical solution, and if the shell lost focus while the script was running, (seemingly) random key presses would take place on the newly focused window.

Comment: I've just tested it. You can use xte to 'simulate' a keypress into the shell, so it'd be possible to build this feature into a bash script, it'd just be buggy and probably sporadic. Here's a snippet of my quick test: (formatting in comments.)
    `01:43 PM lando ~ xte 'key v'; xte 'key i'; xte 'key m'
    
    vim01:43 PM lando ~ vim
    `

Comment: @Landen Thanks for the suggestion, I have been able to get the desired behaviour !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Landen in the comments (thanks a lot!), I've been able to produce a workaround for my problem.

This workaround needs the xautomation package (`xte` command, emulating key pressed), is not very robust, and may depends on the keyboard layout handling of xautomation, and system shortcuts. For example, I had to change the shortcut for the unity HUD.

But given that my command is very fast, and that is is mostly for personal use, this solution fits perfeclty my needs:

```
COMMAND_PASSED='sudo apt-get update'

# Displays the content of $COMMAND_PASSED on the next prompt
xte "str $COMMAND_PASSED"
sleep 0.1
tput cub ${#COMMAND_PASSED}
```

`sleep 0.1` and `tput cub ${#COMMAND_PASSED}` commands are needed to prevent the keys from being also displayed before the command prompt.

`sleep 0.1` makes the whole command to be printed before the prompt.

`tput cub ${#COMMAND_PASSED}` move the cursor backward to make sure that all unnecessary prints are erased.

Thanks everyone!